# Do Ireland and the United Kingdom have a trade alliance similar to NAFTA?

Tags: united-kingdom, economy, trade, republic-of-ireland

Do Ireland and the United Kingdom have a trade alliance similar to NAFTA or USMCA?

Comment: Not a trade deal, but they do have the [Common Travel Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area) which covers free movement, employment, visas, etc.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No. Prior to Brexit the UK and Ireland were in the EU single market. Post Brexit the UK is a third country while Ireland remains in the EU. The UK has to negotiate a bilateral trade deal with the EU as a whole and not Ireland individually.

The UK, EU trade deal is an ongoing point of contention specifically around the details for UK, or more specifically Northern Ireland, and Ireland.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140293/discussion-on-answer-by-jontia-do-ireland-and-the-united-kingdom-have-a-trade-al).

Answer (score 11):

While it is not a full trade agreement, the  [Northern Ireland protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Ireland_Protocol), part of the [treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brexit_withdrawal_agreement) governing the leave of the EU by the United Kingdom, has a number of articles (4–8) that deal with similar objectives.